# Do PhD scholars use Go to implement their research?

Tags: research-process

I am interesting in knowing which languages do PhD implement their research in.
I believe Python is used in NLP research, R and Matlab are used in ML and Data Analysis field.C/C++ is probably used in Networks and Cryptography.
Is Go Lang popular among scholars? If yes then is there any specific field where its preferred?

Comment: They use any language that they know or find relevant to the task...

Comment: Python is very popular among machine learning researchers. I haven't heard of Go being used in academia so I think it's pretty rare. C++ is used by many people who do numerical computing, not just in Networks and Cryptography.

Comment: Yes, occasionally in distributed systems, because that's what Go is good for...

Comment: Still going strong with Fortran 90 in physics :)

Comment: Your question betrays a focus on computer science. Look outside of that, and you'll find a lot of R, MATLAB, FORTRAN, and cobbled-together Excel spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned uses of popoular languages, others were added in comments, let me add C++ for graphics ;-).

Go has advantages over some of those langugaes, but the main question is, in which kind of eco system you are developing. E.g. if all of your fellow PhD candidates are using language A, you should have very, very good reasons for using another language. Here are some reasons:

- You will likely get help / feedback with your code / toolchain if everyone uses the same language.
- It will be easier to built upon existing work (haha - in an optimal world ;-) ) and interoperability beween your work and the one of others will increase.
- Most probably language A has been selected by some purpose (e.g. good libraries, ...) - it is risky to choose different libraries.

On the other hand, if you are more or less working alone and you are either very fluent in Go or you want to learn it, you will have a solid programming environment available.

I personally have not heard of scientists which favour Go over the prementioned languages, even though some try it because they want to learn it. I heard that some people like it for cloud computing.